# binding json data to a dynamic html page i.e. ${approvedby}

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

i have a spring boot program where i have include thymeleaf, spring-boot-starter-web, and lombok dependencies, and when i am trying to run the program it is giving 200 status ok but dont bind the data to the html file

i am trying to bind the data in the html page and return it to the postman consol so that i can understand the job has been done,but instade it returns the same html file that is on main/resources/template without binding the data.

my code for the controller is

```
import com.project.html_2_pdf_complete.Model.Draft;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class DraftController {
    @PostMapping("/draft")
    public ModelAndView bindDraft(@RequestBody Draft draft, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("draftno", draft.getDraftno());
        model.addAttribute("draftsubject", draft.getDraftsubject());
        model.addAttribute("draftcontent", draft.getDraftcontent());
        model.addAttribute("approvedby", draft.getApprovedby());
        model.addAttribute("designation", draft.getDesignation());
        model.addAttribute("approvedon", draft.getApprovedon());

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("draft-template");
         modelAndView.addObject("draft", draft);
        return modelAndView;
//       return "draft-template";
    }
}
```

and my html code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Draft</title>
  <style>
      html, body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 13px;
      }
      body, div, h2, h3, p {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      outline: none;
      font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #666;
      }
      .underlined{
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
      h2 {
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 300;
      text-align: center;
      }
      h3 {
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-align: center;
      }
      .main-block {
        padding: 20px;
        background: #ffffff;
      }
      .content-block{
        padding: 40px 0;
      }
      .designation-block{
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: 600;
      }
      .designation-block p{
        padding: 5px 0;
      }
      .name{
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-block">
  <h2 class="underlined">DFA-${draftno}</h2>
  <h3><b>${draftsubject}</b></h3>
  <div class="content-block">
    ${draftcontent}
  </div>
  <div class="designation-block">
    <p>Signed and Approved by</p>
    <p class="name">${approvedby}</p>
    <p>${designation}</p>
    <p>Dated: ${approvedon}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my application.properties condigerations is

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
 spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
 spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

abd my model is

```
package com.project.html_2_pdf_complete.Model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Draft {
    private String draftno;
    private String draftsubject;
    private String draftcontent;
    private String approvedby;
    private String designation;
    private String approvedon;
}
```

and my dependencies are as followes

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```